# how to make expression language jump across multiple jsp pages?

Tags: java, jsp, variables, spring-mvc, el

I can get some expression language to work but not all. 
This is my route for example. start home.jsp (click on a link takes you to q4.jsp). select a radio button and then click on another link.  takes you to q1.jsp. select a radio button, enter text into a textbox and click another link and finish on results.jsp.

MY PROBLEM:

this is result.jsp

```
Good day **Rich**, for question 1 you chose and for question 2 you chose **Integer**

Total score:
```

Rich is not hardcoded in and the results.jsp actually reads "Good day ${param.elc}". THIS WORKS.
Integer is not hardcoded in and the results.jsp actually reads "and for question 2 you chose ${param.radios1}". THIS WORKS

What does not work is if the jsp page is not directly before where the variable is. q1.jsp leads directly into results.jsp hence the working variables. as seen above, there is no variable after chose, even though the jsp reads for question 1 you chose ${param.radios4}.

Why can jsps only read from the page before? I want q4.jsp to have a variable stored to the end page.

Comment: U r passing these variables as `request` parameters. If u want them to be available throughout ur application then use `session scoped variables`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use session for a conversation between the user and web-app. Since by default your parameters are stored as request attributes as soon as you respond to the first request its gone.

Objects with session scope are accessible from pages processing requests that are in the same session as the one in which they were created. A session is the time users spend using the application, which ends when they close their browser, when they go to another Web site, or when the application designer wants (after a logout, for instance). So, for example, when users log in, their username could be stored in the session and displayed on every page they access. This data lasts until they leave the Web site or log out.

e.g.:

```
    <jsp:useBean id="employee" class="EmployeeBean" scope="session" />
```

or you can save your save your request parameters in session attributes by using a reference of HttpSession Interface.

```
 public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {  

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){  
    try{  


    String n=request.getParameter("userName");  

    HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
    session.setAttribute("uname",n);  

    //code

   }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
  }  

 }
```